# Increasing the size of the text field in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to emulate this website:

[image]

To do this I have the following html code:

```
<div class= "grid">
        <div class= "contact" id= "title">
        <h2 class= "heading font-x2"> Contact message </h2> 
        </div>
  <div class= "contact">
            <img src="01130_bigsurlighthouse_1920x1080.jpg" width="auto" height="200">
        </div>
        <div  class="contact" id= "contact" style = "color: steelblue">
            <p class = "contact">Here, the input field gets a color when it gets focus (clicked on):</p>

            <form id = "">
              
              <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
            </form>
            <form id = "form">
              
              <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
            </form>
            
            
      </form>
        </div>
```

And my `CSS` file looks like this:

```
.contact {
    color: black;
    background: white;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    
    
}
.heading{margin-bottom:20px; font-size:4rem;}
#title{
    
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.font-x2{font-size:1.6rem;}
#service{
    color:green;
    float:center; margin:0 0 20px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#form {
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: 203px;
    
    
}
.grid   {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
 }

.grid div:nth-child(even) {
    
background-color: red;
}
.grid div:nth-child(odd) {
    
background-color: green;
}
```

This produces a `contactus` page which looks like this:

[image]

I understand the color is not right to say the least. What I am wondering is how can i make the text field large in CSS stylesheet. As you can see they did not increase the font size to increase the size of the input field.
My second question is that I had to create 2 forms so have the input field stacked. Is there a way to stack the input field in CSS itself ?
Could you please advise how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to use `display: flex` on container for right side to have children aligned vertically, and `align-items: stretch` helps to make them as wide as possible. I've also combined `input` and `p` under the `form` and fixed id (in `css` you were referencing non-existing `#form` id).

```css
.contact {
    color: black;
    background: white;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

.heading {
    margin-bottom:20px; font-size:4rem;
}

#title {
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
    font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
}

.font-x2 {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
}

#service{
    color:green;
    float:center; margin:0 0 20px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 0px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#names {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
}

#names > * {
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0 1em 1em;
}

#names input {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: red;
}

.grid div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class= "grid">
  <div class= "contact" id= "title">
    <h2 class= "heading font-x2"> Contact message </h2> 
  </div>
  <div class="contact">
  </div>
  <div class="contact" id="contact" style="color: steelblue">
    <form id="names">
      <p class="contact">
        Here, the input field gets a color when it gets focus (clicked on):
      </p>
            
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey regarding you second question you can just put them inside one form. This comes handy in case you submit the form, as you have to submit only one and not multiple forms.

```
<form id = "contact-form">
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
</form>
```

Then you can style the contact form in your css `#contact-form` in order to stack or put the forms in column. I would suggest `display:block` or `display:flex` + `flex-direction: column` (I prefer flex as it is more useful as you can also align-items where you want inside the div e.g `align-items: center` or use `justify-content: space-between` or `space-around` to play where your elements will be placed inside your `div`.

```
#contact-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Now, back to your first question. To change the input size you can directly apply css to your `input` tags. Note that input can be of different type e.g `text`, `email`, `password` etc. In order to apply different style to different fonts you can access them `input[text]` on your css. You can also apply same style to all `inputs` by just selecting `input` on css. For instance you can try the following:

```
input[type="text"] {
    font-size: 16px;
    width=150px
    height=20px
}
```

You can also specify the `width` and `height` in your input tag directly on your html file with inline style.

```
<input type="text" id="name" style="width: 200px; height: 40px">
```

You can define the size (i.e width) inside the `input` tag as below:

```
<input type="text" id="name" size="200">
```

In your `input` you can also define different constraints as well e.g minlength = minimum length allowed to that input field, or `required` so the filed will be required when you submit the form, etc...

Furthermore you can also use `javascript` to style the iinput if you are interested. Have a look https://www.techiedelight.com/set-width-input-textbox-html-css-javascript/

Answer (score -2):

add this to your CSS to increase the  font size of your input field

```
input { 
  font-size: 4em;
}
```